# AWS EC2 unable to reach Instance with HTTPS set to 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance has the following security rules:

[image: My EC2 instance security rules]

Unfortunately, if I browse its public IP address via HTTPS, I get "Unable to reach the site", while if I browse it via HTTP it works as it should.

[image: Browser error message]

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - I had to set Apache to listen on port 443.